# NFC C# Application

Tags: c#, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p

Hi I don't know if this is possible because I have been searching for hours with no leads.
I want to make a C# program on desktop that is connected to the ACR122u reader. I want to be able to read and store the NDEF message value as a string for processing. Is this even possible if so where do I begin?

Note: I have looked and examined the examples supplied with the ACR122u reader but none have worked for me or even displayed the message I stored from a third part application.

Answer (score 2):

[According to this website](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&id=ACR122U) that reader is PC/SC compliant. You should be able to access it via that interface. [See here for an example](http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2010/11/pcsc-sample-in-c.html). Here is a highly-rated [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET) along the same lines, except it features a wrapper for the complex PC/SC commands.

(Click the downloads link on the [product site](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&id=ACR122U) to get to the PC/SC driver downloads.)